# Ajuda Script de upload Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em PHP com upload de fotos, e como queria uma thumbnail da foto antes de enviar para o banco, encontrei a seguinte função Jquery:

```
jQuery(function($){

    var fileDiv = document.getElementById("upload3");
    var fileInput = document.getElementById("upload-image3");
    console.log(fileInput);
    fileInput.addEventListener("change",function(e){
      var files = this.files
      showThumbnail(files)
    },false)

    fileDiv.addEventListener("click",function(e){
      $(fileInput).show().focus().click().hide();
      e.preventDefault();
    },false)

    fileDiv.addEventListener("dragenter",function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
    },false);

    fileDiv.addEventListener("dragover",function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
    },false);

    fileDiv.addEventListener("drop",function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();

      var dt = e.dataTransfer;
      var files = dt.files;

      showThumbnail(files)
    },false);

    function showThumbnail(files){
      for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
        var file = files[i]
        var imageType = /image.*/
        if(!file.type.match(imageType)){
          console.log("Not an Image");
          continue;
        }

        var image = document.createElement("img");
        // image.classList.add("")
        var thumbnail = document.getElementById("thumbnail4");
        image.file = file;
        thumbnail.appendChild(image)

        var reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = (function(aImg){
          return function(e){
            aImg.src = e.target.result;
          };
        }(image))
        var ret = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        image.onload= function(){
          ctx.drawImage(image,100,100)
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Porém esse código está dando suporte para multiupload, e está ai o problema. Se uma foto já foi inserida, ao clicar novamente para adicionar foto, a nova foto deve substituir a que já estava na thumbnail ao invés de ir para o banco junto! Aguardo ansiosamente vossos ensinamentos.

Comment: O seu input file está parecido com esse: <input type="file" name="img" multiple> ? Se sim basta tirar o "multiple" que funciona como você precisa.

Comment: Tem como você colocar os códigos completos para eu simular aqui na minha máquina e poder te ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Te aconselho a utilizar algum plugin jquery para fazer isso, da uma pesquisada por uploadify, ele tem varias opções de customizações, aceita muiti arquivos ou apenas um, igual você procura.
Aqui tem um tutorial = http://www.oficinadanet.com.br/post/9518-upload-de-imagens-php-com-uploadify

Comment: Funciona 100% o uploadify